# Blender mirroring not working

Tags: mirror

I'm trying to use the mirror modifier in blender, but when I do, the duplicated half won't change with the normal half. I made a video about it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtCjKHoL2uw&feature=youtu.be

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You applied the modifier, that's why.

I only have a short time to explain, but I'll try:

Modifiers are non-destructive while they have been added to an object, but not yet applied. Once a modifier is applied, the effect is committed to the mesh permananetly. It's kind of like flattening layers in GIMP or Photoshop. It's a one-way street.

There are times when you want to apply a modifier and times when you don't. If, for example, you had sculpted a symmetrical body using the Mirror Modifier, but then wanted to sculpt spikes on just one arm, obviously you would want to apply the modifier and then do the non-symmetrical parts.

Comment: Oh my god thank you, I'm fairly new to blender.